# multiple intents from given a input text?

Tags: nlp, opennlp, multiclass-classification

Can we have a model which distinguishes sentence with intent from a given input text like in the example below?

> "Turn the bathroom light off and remind me to take the trash out."

There are two independent intents here: *turn_lights, set_reminder*.

Similarly in another example:

> "Hey what's up? do you guys offer free trial?"

there are two intents here : *greetings , product_pricing*

Thanks & Regards,
Achyuta nanda Sahoo

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are addressing is *multilabel* or *multiclass classification*. In machine learning, there are algorithms you can train models to label multi-intents as listed in [Wiki page for multilabel classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) .

Another approach would be one-label classification and get probabilities of intents for your instances and select the labels that are above the thresholds that you selected.

Hope this helps,

Cheers